# Including new Javascript only after a comment is made

Tags: posts, comments, comment-form

I am looking to call a new javascript function only after a new comment has been made by a user. Specifically, I want to include new javascript on the resulting page of the page reload after submitting the new comment form on a blog post.

Does anyone know how to do this?

My end goal is that I want to make a call using Mixpanel's (http://www.mixpanel.com) javascript API call and make an event called "Comment added" for a specific user. I know how to do the mixpanel side of things but am confused by the this specific use case of wordpress.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not so clear where exactly you would want to "inject" this JS .
`"After a new comment has been made"` , in WP terms and php workflow, can mean several things . (for example when the $POST request is made , when the action is triggered ,when it is getting checked, sanitized , when it is inserted to the DB etc etc ..)

Anyhow ,you will need to search for the right [wp actions](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference) / [filters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference) that you can hook into , like the `comment_post` action ( unfortunately undocumented in codex - GIYBF ) ,or the  `comment_post_redirect` filter (Also undocumented in codex)  or [`wp_insert_comment`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_insert_comment) action (runs AFTER comment inserted to DB)  and use those actions to include the JS ..

for example :

```
add_action ('comment_post','my_comments_js_function');// runs when comments are POSTED
```

and then

```
my_comments_js_function(){
// do your JS stuff.
}
```

But like I said, it is not really clear to me what exactly you want and WHEN .

Comment: Thanks Krembo, This should help me get started! As far as 'when', I believe the best time would after the comment has been added to DB and when the page is reloaded to show the new comment. Either way, I appreciate the help!